# How to design a scheduler alarm system using android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am creating an android app which will serve as a scheduler. The client is allowed to enter all his schedules for the  1 month ahead.

For instance

Monday      22/12/2016     2:30am        Go for work
Tuesday    23/12/2016      4:00pm        Visit a friend
   .....

Now a user is allowed to enter all this information into the local sqlite database of the app.

Please with this information in the database,  would it be possible for the system to send a notification with an alarm to the user interface when the time schedule is due, even when the app has been closed?

I would very glad if someone can give any ideas or links as to how to go about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You can store you information in sqlite database. Then with data from database you will be able to get the information and set the alarm with `Pending intent` .

You can set both repeating and non repeating alarm.

Use `wake lock permission` in the manifest to keep the screen on and awake from lock condition and show your alarm screen with information.

With `RingtoneManager` it is possible to play some music too when alarm fires.

And most importantly if the phone restarts or put off and then again put on when the boot completes the `alarm service` will set all your alarm automatically.

Basically these are the main steps to build an alarm system. For an example see below repository in Github

https://github.com/zahansafallwa/AlarmClock

Its a bit of complex coding but this one more or less includes all the possible staffs you can do with alarm manager in android

Comment: Safaliwa , please I am working a similar project with this same repository but im encountering some challenges. Please see this if you can be of help  http://stackoverflow.com/q/35304758/2595059  Thanks so well

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is couple of months old, but still I want to answer, answer by @Zahan Safallwa is corrent but you need to manage `Pending Intent`, `Request Code`, `Intent for Pending Intent` and `Time/delays` for alarms. This will increase exponentially if you have multiple alarms. For the purpose I had a wrote a class which will help you out.

**Sample Usage: For scheduling**

```
new ScheduleAlarm( context )
  .withRequestCode( REQUEST_CODE )
  .forClass( SomeIntentService.class )
  .withDelay( 0 )
  .withRepeatsIn( TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS )
  .schedule();
```

**Sample Usage:For re-scheduling-Post kitkat**

```
new ScheduleAlarm( context )
  .withRequestCode( REQUEST_CODE )
  .forClass( SomeIntentService.class )
  .withDelay( TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS )
  .withRepeatsIn( TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS )
  .reSchedule();
```

**Sample Usage:Stops alarm**

```
new ScheduleAlarm( context )
  .withRequestCode( REQUEST_CODE )
  .forClass( SomeIntentService.class )
  .stopAlarm();
```

It is available on [GIST](https://gist.github.com/murtazakhussain/adc344620e821417ac9b4fda5c6b8e5d)